# Text Indentation on React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I need to indent the first line of a paragraph on React Native. But the use of the common css `text-indent` property (`textIndent`) isn't compatible with React Native, and neither are pseudo-element selectors (like `:first-line`). Is there any way to do this without wrapping the whole line in `<Text>` tags and defining its own style? Which words will end up in the first line of a paragraph is somewhat indeterministic from one device's viewport to another device's viewport.

Answer (score 13):

Use `{'\t'}`. Just like this: 
`<Text>{'\t'}Hi there</Text>`

Comment: Hi there! This works great until the line breaks automatically in the Text-Component because of the text length. Do you have a solution to keep the indentation also after an automatic line break ? Edit: For example like a enumeration, so the "1." is not indented but the following text is.

Comment: This one works perfect. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

For a purely CSS solution.

```
//styles.js

text: {
  paddingLeft: 10,
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score -6):

I was able to get the text-indent to work in my react webapp with the below syntax:

```js
//info.js

import './App.css'

export default class Info extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        history: {
          goBack: () => { }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <div id='info'>
          <h2>Info</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
       </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```css
//App.css

div#info p {
  text-indent: 20px;
}
```

Comment: This question is about react-native. Your code is for react app.

Comment: Question is about react native not react js