# React Native Multi Line Text Indentation

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

In React Native, the line breaks automatically in the Text component due to the length of the text. How do I keep the desired indentation after an automatic line break?

[Text Indentation on React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994521/text-indentation-on-react-native)

This question answers how to create indentation using the text component, but does not address multi line indentation like user3191334 asked about.

For example, if we used single line indentation

```
<Text>{'\t'}Hello, my name is John.</Text>
```

The output on a mobile screen could be:

```
     Hello, my name is 

 John.
```

I would like to make it so the output is:

```
     Hello, my name is

     John.
```

Answer (score 0):

add `paddingLeft` property in the text style. Here is an example

```
<Text style={{paddingLeft:100}}>this is just and example </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use /n for break line

```
<Text>
   Hi{'\n'}
   this is a test message.
</Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

React native parses whatever you put in {`some text`}.
In your example you can use it like this:

```
<Text>
    {`Hello, my name is
    
         John.`}
</Text>
```